# Зачем прописывать класс для каждой таблицы бд

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

```
class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<int> ExamScores { get; set; }
}
```

Заметил такую тему в объяснении `IEnumerable` на MSDN. Вопрос, если у меня множество сущностей из бд необходимо вытянуть, мне таких классов бесконечно плодить, пока не закончатся нужные таблицы? И если у меня около 10 атрибутов в сущности, получается, чтобы хотя бы 2 вывести, нужно 20 строк? не слишком? можно как-то это упростить?
Также вопрос, как мне лучше вывести двоичный тип данных image в `IEnumerable`

Comment: При чем тут WPF и MVVM, если вопрос про базу? Ставьте значит теги EF или через что там общение с базой у вас, убирайте лишние, и акцентируйте вопрос конкретно на базе. А то я захожу, думаю "вот, что-то интересное по WPF", а тут на тебе, база...) Или вы про ViewModel/Model слои? Если да, то пишите там только нужное, не заставляют ведь описывать всю базу.

Comment: `чтобы хотя бы 2 вывести` что в вашем понимании значит вывести? Классы должны соответствовать базе данных, чтобы они были связаны с базой данных, в этом, типо, смысл :/

Comment: если вы хотите автоматически создать модели из существующей базы даных, то [вот](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/existing-database) туториал

Comment: @iiKuzmychov я такие вещи осуждаю, пробовал юзать модель ado net, супер муторно и если я что-то меняю в бд, то это не синхронизируется с моделькой в проекте

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, за ответ, в принципе я узнал, что хотел, и да, это крутая тема, осталось понять как мне из DataSet превратить в коллекцию, но этого добра куча, всем спасибо